# Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type

Tags: c#, delegates, visual-studio-2012, windowsformshost

Having done nothing more than install Visual Studio 2012, our existing application now crashes when attempting to create a delegate.

Why would we be getting this error when running our application (not running in debug...just running the .exe normally...not having re-compiled, or done anything other than install Visual Studio 2012)?

Does Visual Studio 2012 update .net 4.0 WindowsFormsIntegration in some way?

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'MyWindowsFormsHost' that matches the
>   specified binding constraints threw an exception.'

With internal exception:

> Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security
>   transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type

The offending class and line:

```
internal class MyWindowsFormsHost : WindowsFormsHost
{
    private delegate void NotifyChildFocus(ref Message m);
    private readonly NotifyChildFocus childGotFocus;

    public MyWindowsFormsHost()
    {
         //this line crashes now (and did not before VS2012 install)
         this.childGotFocus = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(NotifyChildFocus),
                                 this, "NotifyActivateApp") as NotifyChildFocus;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Discovered that the NotifyActiveateApp method no longer exists on WindowsFormsHost.  What I don't understand is how installing .net 4.5 with visual studio 2012 has affected my existing 4.0 application.

UPDATE: In order to get around this, I've used reflection to check if the NotifyActivateApp method exists.  (If it doesn't exist, then the app is running in the patched .net version...and I don't have to worry about the activation bug this child focus code was written to fix).

```
    MethodInfo methodInfo = (typeof(WindowsFormsHost)).GetMethod("NotifyActivateApp", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (methodInfo != null)
{
     this.childGotFocus = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(NotifyChildFocus), this, "NotifyActivateApp") as NotifyChildFocus;
}
```

Note to Microsoft: Thanks for fixing your bug...I just wish you would have rolled it out in a way that didn't break existing code.

Comment: Installing VS2012 probably upgraded the .NET runtime to v4.5, which changed something.  No idea what changed though.

Comment: Is your NotifyActiveApp method non-public? Have you checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12f294ye.aspx and subsequently http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc.aspx? And possibly even this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103.aspx. Down the rabbit hole.

Comment: NotifyActiveApp is on the base class: WindowsFormsHost.  I have looked at those actually.  I have not tried changing security for reflection, but I will.  I'm confused about why this would happen, since our application was compiled against .net v4.0.

Comment: As far as how installing .Net 4.5 affected your 4.0 application, take a look at [this post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40) by [Rick Strahl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/11197/rick-strahl).